# Advice needed with use of Maps from the java collection frameworks

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to understand how a `Map` from the Java Collections Framework works. I understand that it maps values to a key, but what if I want to create an employee who has a *first name*, *last name*, *gender*, and an *ID* (which I would use as the key).

So I tried this code...

```
Map <Employee> employeeMap = new HashMap<String,String,String,String,int>();
```

But it doesn't like this, as it wants only two parameters to be entered. So, how do I add an entire employee to the `Map` which contains more then two values?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an Employee class, don't you?

```
class Employee{
Integer id;
String firstname;
String lastname;
...
}
```

when you have an object of Employee, say "`em`"
then you can

```
employeeMap.put(em.getId(), em);
```

Comment: aha I see. Will that then store the entire em object as an array list would??

Comment: didn't get you... of course you can put a String[]/Object[] or List/Set contains (firstname, lastname.. whatever), instead of putting in an Employee object. but I don't think it is a good way.